# Es correcto mezclar variables int y double haciendo casts?

Tags: c++

¿Es una mala practica la que realizo en este programa mezclando variables / constantes de tipo int con otras de tipo double? ¿Deberia declararlas todas como double y no hacer tanto cast?

Gracias.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::fixed;

int main() {
    int horas; // Total de horas trabajadas
    double tarifa; // Sueldo por hora
    const int horasMax = 40; // A partir de cuantas horas se facturara como hora extra y se aplicara la tarifa especial "excedente"
    const double excedente = 1.5; // Precio de la hora extra

    cout << "Introduzca las horas trabajadas (-1 para salir): ";
    cin >> horas;

    cout.precision(2);

    while(horas != -1) {
            cout << "Introduzca la tarifa por hora del empleado ($00.00): ";
            cin >> tarifa;

            if(horas <= horasMax)
                    cout << "El salario es: " << fixed << static_cast<double>(horas) * tarifa << "\n";
            else
                    cout << "El salario es: " << fixed << (static_cast<double>(horas - horasMax) * (tarifa * excedente)) + (static_cast<double>(horasMax) * tarifa) << "\n";

            cout << "Introduzca las horas trabajadas (-1 para salir): ";
            cin >> horas;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No está mal visto multiplicar un entero por un valor de punto flotante y es una operación válida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como ya ha mencionado [Bloodday](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8635/2742) , podría ser más eficiente utilizar el mismo tipo para todas las operaciones... al fin y al cabo ¿para qué usas enteros para almacenar horas? ¿acaso no existen fracciones de horas? ¿Qué pasa si un trabajador ha trabajado 63 minutos? ¿o 111 minutos?

Sin embargo, por el diseño de tu código, es "*necesario*" que la variable `horas` sea un entero ya que usas esta variable tanto para control del flujo del programa como para hacer cálculos.

Dado que los números en coma flotante son conocidos por la imprecisión que tienen para reflejar ciertos números (por ejemplo, es imposible expresar exáctamente el número 0.1, así que se hace una aproximación); esta imprecisión hace que comparaciones por equidad en números en coma flotante esté desaconsejada, porque podría darse el caso que `0.1 == (1.0 / 10.0)` ¡resultase ser falso!

Esto hace "*obligatorio*" el tipo entero para `horas` pues usas una comparación de equidad (bueno, inequidad en este caso); seguramente comparar la inequidad de `horas` como `double` directamente contra `-1.0` no de problemas pero si `horas` se usase en cálculos antes de hacer la comprobación de inequidad podría fallar la condición incluso si supuestamete debíera haberse cumplido.

Dicho esto, te aconsejo usar una variable `double` para horas y una variable de control para el flujo, por ejemplo: tras la operación preguntar:

> ```
> ¿Desea continuar? (S/N)
> ```

Y utilizar una variable `char`, así la variable `horas` tendrá una [única responsabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica).

---

Para acabar, no necesitas las transformaciones de tipos en las operaciones:

```
static_cast<double>(horas) * tarifa
static_cast<double>(horas - horasMax) * (tarifa * excedente)) + (static_cast<double>(horasMax) * tarifa
```

Ya que los enteros serán [promocionados a `double` implícitamente](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) (el resaltado es mío):

> #### Conversiones
>
> Si el operando pasado a un operador aritmético es un valor integral o un enumerado sin ámbito, antes de cualquier otra acción, el operando es promocionado a integral.
>
> Para los operadores binarios (excepto desplazamientos), **si los operandos promocionados tienen diferentes tipos, se aplican normas adicionales de conversiones, conocidas como "conversiones aritméticas usuales" con el objetivo de producir un tipo común**:
>
> - Si alguno de los operandos es un enumerado con ámbito, no se realiza ninguna conversión: ambos operandos deben tener el mismo tipo.
> - En caso contrario, si alguno de los operandos es `long double` el otro operando es convertido a `long double`.
> - **En caso contrario, si alguno de los operandos es `double` el otro operando es convertido a `double`**.
> - En caso contrario, si alguno de los operandos es `float` el otro operando es convertido a `float`.

Por lo tanto, si decides conservar el tipo entero para `horas`, con toda tranquilidad puedes quitar la conversión explícita de tu código pues ya existe una conversión implícita; quitar esos `static_cast` innecesarios hará el código un poco más fácil de leer.

Answer (score 1):

Desde el punto de vista del rendimiento, es mejor hacer que las variables sean de tipo double, ya que el cast es una funcion que requiere tiempo de procesamiento.

Aunque en un programa como el que muestras, es un tiempo que no es apreciable y puedes hacerlo como quieras, si fuese una rutina que debiera repetirse una gran cantidad de veces y dar respuesta lo mas rapido posible, con el cast son milisegundos que se acumulan y se convierten en segundos haciendo que parezca que la aplicacion se ha quedado colgada.